# How to check blob input string is hex in java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, oracle

In our product, in a java class we are receiving `Blob` in string format and we need to check whether this incoming blob is a hex string (`Blob` can be of any size) and based on the boolean result we will decide further `Blob` processing(because in our case `MS-SQL` is returning Hex and `MySQL`,`Oracle` are returning pure `Blob`). Is it good practice to use `Pattern`, `Matcher` and `matches()` to check whether this incoming `Blob` is `hex` string ?

Following is my code snippet :

```
public static boolean isHexadecimal(String blobdata) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9a-fA-F]+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(blobdata);

    if (m.matches()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is the other option? If the database returns "pure Blob" that's not a String at all, isn't it?

Comment: @Thilo Will it (above code snippet) be slower in execution if the blob contain large amount of data ?

Comment: Please explain what form the "pure Blob" has and how you retrieved it from the database.

Comment: @Thilo ""pure blob" mean as it is unlike MS-SQL which is returning a hex string, we are retrieving it with a simple select query to third party application and we are then receiving it in the form of string.

Comment: So it is text data? What is the database column type? "Blob" (and hex-encoded) usually implies binary data.

Comment: Also note that this method does not work with a "pure blob" that happens to contain only hex characters. I would not decide this on the fly by looking at the data. You know what database you are using, set a flag accordingly (in configuration or determined from JDBC database url or name). Avoid the performance hit and the uncertainty.

Comment: @Thilo Data can be image,xml,text but in MS-SQL it is been stored as a HEX string only.DB column type can be image or varbinary. Will this above code snippet be okay ? or will it consume time for large blob data ?

Comment: You cannot store an image in a String in Java.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93572/discussion-between-sudeep-masare-and-thilo).

Comment: @Thilo, [of course you can](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: @MickMnemonic: The question talks about "pure blob". No mention of Base64 (or another encoding). So is this about detecting Base64 vs hex-encoding?

Comment: @MickMnemonic Hello Mick, we just want to identify Hex,that's it. will the above code snippet work correctly ?

Comment: I really don't understand what are the different types of `String`s you're expecting to receive in `blobdata`. Can you give an example of a `String` that represents a "pure blob"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex sports a deficiency insofar as it only flags that your blobdata contains a substring in hexadecimal ( not even taking into account that the number of consecutive hex bytes must be even if it represents an octet sequence ). Use start/end anchors to rectify that:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[0-9a-fA-F]+$");
```

An alternative might be to invert the matching ruling out the occurrence of non-hex data in your blob. Of course, this is only viable if you are indeed after hex-only content:

```
public static boolean isHexadecimal(String blobdata) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^0-9a-fA-F]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(blobdata);

    if (m.matches()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code

```
public class HexTester
{
  private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile ("^[0-9a-fA-F]+$");

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println (isHexadecimal ("0102"));
    System.out.println (isHexadecimal ("xx0102"));
    System.out.println (isHexadecimal ("deadbeef"));
    System.out.println (isHexadecimal ("xxdeadbeef"));
  }

  private static boolean isHexadecimal (String blobdata)
  {
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher (blobdata);
    return m.matches ();
  }
}
```

Your regex would return true if it found any hex characters, this one checks that the entire string is valid hexadecimal.

Also, the pattern should only be compiled once, not every time you call the function.

If you want to be sure that the hex digits always come in pairs, you could use this

```
private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile ("^(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+$");
```

Comment: What if the size of my blob is very large ? will it (the matches()) consume time in execution ?